# Getting this issue in Xcode while integrating react-native-google-signin " ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.h:30:1: Expected ','"

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I was trying to implement the `react-native-google-signin` in iOS but I am stuck with this issue. It is throwing the below error:

> "/Users/mohitbaghel/workspace/goodleDrive/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.h:28:26: Expected ','  /*! @file OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.h".

I am using `react-native` version `0.61.2`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "OIDExternalUserAgent.h"

@class SFSafariViewController;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

/*! @brief An iOS specific external user-agent that uses the best possible user-agent available
        depending on the version of iOS to present the request.
 */
API_UNAVAILABLE(macCatalyst)
@interface OIDExternalUserAgentIOS : NSObject<OIDExternalUserAgent>

- (nullable instancetype)init API_AVAILABLE(ios(11))
    __deprecated_msg("This method will not work on iOS 13, use "
                     "initWithPresentingViewController:presentingViewController");

/*! @brief The designated initializer.
    @param presentingViewController The view controller from which to present the
        \SFSafariViewController.
 */
- (nullable instancetype)initWithPresentingViewController:
    (UIViewController *)presentingViewController
    NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Can you share your XCode version? Can you also detail how you configured your iOS react native project to work with this library (Using Cocoa Pods or manually)?

Comment: I have same problem

Comment: Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61), React-Native Version 0.61.2, ReactJs Version 16.9.0, react-native-firebase version "~5.6.0", react-native-google-signin version "1.0.0-rc8", In my podfile i used these versions pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0.0'

  pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'  

  pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin'

Comment: Have you fixed the problem, fellow RN developers?